# Flutter : POS Thermal Printer Unhandled Exception: PlatformException

Tags: flutter, posprinter

I want the Pos Thermal Printer to print a receipt using MethodChannel().invokeMethod. The printer can run the print command in debug mode, but cannot run in release mode and gives the following error message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctIkW.png)

please help If I've done something wrong.

I've tried looking around the web for an answer with no way to fix it.